# Show only commits into certain branch on Sublime Merge

Tags: git, sublimemerge

How can I filter my commit view to show only the commits *into* my master branch? To filter all the noise of seeing commits on all the other branches.

In [Sourcetree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) this would be filtering "First Parent Only" on a given branch.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As of build 1070, you can do this by Alt-clicking the eye icon on the branch name in the location bar:

**Example**:

[image]

Comment: Nice, beat me to it! Just noticed it land in 1070

Answer (score 9):

Build 1107 has a pretty convenient solution to the OP's problem. (I'm not sure if that's when they started including it though).

[image: Context menu option]

Simply right-click on the commit that the branch you want to isolate is at and choose to hide all branches except the relevant one.

Answer (score 2):

In the current version of sublimemerge (1065) this isn't available.

Comment: If this changes in future versions of Sublime Merge I will update the answer

Comment: now you can remove the answer instead?